# ImportError: No module named 'azure' when running python script on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, azure, module, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send data to the Azure Blob Storage and my first step was to just check the connection by using the sample code I found on the tutorial website:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)

blob_service.create_container(
    'mycontainername',
    public_access=PublicAccess.Blob
)

blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(
    'mycontainername',
    'myblobname',
    b'<center><h1>Hello World!</h1></center>',
    content_settings=ContentSettings('text/html')
)

print(blob_service.make_blob_url('mycontainername', 'myblobname'))
```

Of course entered the account name and the account key. But I get this error, which I also get when using my own python script so this is a big problem for me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "azuretest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
ImportError: No module named 'azure'
```

I am a beginner in this topic and I am very lost. Can anyone tell me what to do? Thanks

Comment: how did you install that module? create a venv and use a fresh venv for experiments, install module into that

Answer (score 1):

Installing just the `azure-storage` library should be sufficient in stead of installing the entire SDK.

```
pip install azure-storage
```

### Edit

I see you have already done this. The package might not be in your python path. You could try adding

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages')
```

at the top of your script (but I am not 100% sure that it will be there on your syste, it is on ubuntu)

or append it to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: @xoani If you try to run `pip install azure` (or azure.storage) then it will say that it is alreadyt installed and where it is installed. Please check that the directory is correct.

Comment: Correct package name is "azure-storage", not "azure.storage" (Niklas I edited your post). Note that this is not the recommended package anymore, it's "azure-storage-blob", but that's not related to your problem.